Model State is always false in ASP.NET MVC
I am writing an ASP.NET MVC application which has an employee and its designation. Designation is populated in a drop down list. Not sure why am I getting the model state as always false and hence the employee is not able to be saved.
Code that is used to populate the designation drop down is as below.
Any help will be highly appreciated.
public void PopulateDesignations()
{
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> myDesig = ObjDB.Designations
                                               .Select(i => new SelectListItem { Text = i.DesignationName, Value = i.DesignationID.ToString() });

    ViewBag.Designations = myDesig;
}

Controller method here which is called when Create employee method is called via POST
Create employee view file code here
Tried to troubleshoot but failed
Code in CreateEmployee.cshtml
@model EmployeeEntity

<th>hhh</th>
<th> @ViewBag.Message </th>

<form name="CreatEmployeeForm" asp-action="CreateEmployee" asp-controller="Employee">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmployeeName) </td>
            <td><input type="text" asp-for="EmployeeName" />  </td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeName)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DesignationID) </td>
            <td><select asp-items="ViewBag.Designations" asp-for="DesignationID"></select></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Create Employee Create" />
</form>

Code in Employee Controller
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CreateEmployee(EmployeeEntity objEmployee )
    {

        //Model.Designation = obj.Designation.Find(Model.DesignationId);

        objEmployee.Designation = ObjDB.Designations.Find(objEmployee.DesignationID);


        if (ModelState.IsValid == true)
        {
            ObjDB.Employees.Add(objEmployee);
            ObjDB.SaveChanges();
            ViewBag.Message = "Employee Created Sucessfully";
            return RedirectToAction("ShowAllEmployees");
    }
        else
        {
            //PopulateDesignations();
            PopulateDesignations();
            return View("CreateEmployee");
            //return RedirectToAction("CreateEmployee");
            //return View(objEmployee);
}

}
But I am still facing issue where the model.state is always retirning false...
EmployeeEntity Code here
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace EmployeeManagementSystem.Models
{
    public class EmployeeEntity
    {
        [Key]
       
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }


        //[Required (ErrorMessage ="Employee name cannot be empty")]
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }


        
        [ForeignKey("DesignationID")]
        public int DesignationID { get; set; }

        public virtual  DesignationEntity Designation { get; set; }

    }
}


Share your relevant code how you are submitting the request and how's the controller code looks like.

Thanks for response @MdFaridUddinKiron , I have now added code snippets..

Need the EmployeeEntity class details as well.

@MdFaridUddinKiron , please find the employeentity code as well, many thanks in adavnce for all your help really appreciate

The model is clearly wrong. You put foreign key that refers to DesignationID and you do not have anything under the DesignationID under the virtual class. Change it to ForeignKey["Designation"] instead. It got to tbe same description.

Many thanks @YatFeiLeong , below trick has worked with adding  a ?                       public int DesignationID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DesignationID")]
    public virtual DesignationEntity? Designation { get; set; }



I am writing an ASP.NET MVC application which has an employee and its
designation. Designation is populated in a drop down list. Not sure
why am I getting the model state as always false and hence the
employee is not able to be saved.

Based on your shared code snippet and description I have tried to simulate your scenario and founded that, you are using EmployeeEntity model while submitting the form value to the CreateEmployee.
However, are not sending any value for public virtual DesignationEntity Designation { get; set; } property from your submitted form value which causing the ModelState.IsValid always false.
In order to fix the issue, either make that model nullable or pass the value in it.
I have made the DesignationEntity model nullable  as following and getting the correct value which set the ModelState.IsValid  to true.
public class EmployeeEntity
{
    [Key]

    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }


    //[Required (ErrorMessage ="Employee name cannot be empty")]
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }



    [ForeignKey("DesignationID")]
    public int DesignationID { get; set; }

    public virtual DesignationEntity? Designation { get; set; }
}

Apart from that, you don't need to compare true conditional like this ModelState.IsValid == true instead you could do is if (ModelState.IsValid) it will check if the value is true or not.
Output:



Note: Please refer to this official document for additional details.

Many thanks it has now fixed the issue , thank you so much!!!
